# How to filter negative numbers in a column and pass their absolute number to another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
T1  T2
-3  3
 2   
-2  2
-1  1
```

How can I filter the negative numbers from T1 and pass the absolute number from the negatives to T2?

Comment: What do you mean by `pass the absolute number from the negatives to T2`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html), for positive numbers is better get `NaN`s for numeric `T2` column:

```
df['T2'] = np.where(df.T1.gt(0), np.nan, df.T1.abs())
#alternative
#df['T2'] = np.where(df.T1 > 0, np.nan, df.T1.abs())
```